# MS Access switch query not ending after first condition is met

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, switch-statement, select-query

I am trying to run a select query in MS Access  whose values being evaluated meet more than one criteria (ie: date ranges).  The results for the below query include duplicates because the statement keeps evaluating even after the first statement is met.  What am I doing wrong in this statement, or is this not the correct statement to use?  I have tried using iif statements but they also have the same result.

```
Primary Rec: Switch(
  [tblData].[Beg Dt] >= [qryPrimaryRt].[Beg Dt]
  And [tblData].[End Dt] <= [qryPrimaryRt].[End Dt]
, [qryPrimaryRt].[Primary Rec]
, [qryRtByMaxDays].[Primary Rec] Is Not Null
  And (
    [tblData].[Beg Dt] < [qryPrimaryRt].[Beg Dt]
    Or [tblData].[End Dt] < [qryPrimaryRt].[End Dt]
  )
, [qryRtByMaxDays].[Primary Rec]
, [tblData].[TOC] = 117 Or [tblData].[TOC] = 297
, [tblData].[Rec Loc Name]
)
```

Comment: It seems your query includes a data source (table or another query) named `[W12/13, S13]`.  Please consider the comma in that name makes it extra challenging for us to analyze the `Switch` statement.  If you can't change the name, alias it in your query.  Then add the full `SELECT` statement to your question ... you can get that from SQL View in the Access query designer.  Showing us sample data which illustrates the duplicates would also help us understand the problem.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect your suggestion of changing the naming convention used, thanks for the advice.